How to send OTLP traces from Kafka to Jaeger? How to use Jaeger as Kafka consumer?
I have deployed one application on K8s cluster which is instrumented using Opentelemetry. It is emitting traces and those traces are collected by OTEL collector. Then, using Kafka exporter in OTEL collector, I am sending those traces to Kafka as statefulset on another K8s cluster. I am able to send those traces as messages using topic "otlp_spans" to Kafka broker. Now, I have deployed Jaeger:All-in-one on the same cluster.
I want to send those traces from Kafka to this Jaeger. So, my question is how I should define this Jaeger as Kafka consumer which will subscribe to the "otlp_span" topic and I can traces in Jaeger?
Or, should I create custom Kafka sink connector for Jaeger? If so, how to create this Kafka sink connector?
My OTEL, Kafka and Jaeger setup:


I have already generated traces in otlp_json format. How can I create my own custom openetelemetry exporter using Python which will send those traces to Jaeger collector?

Jaeger v1 does not accept OTLP data over Kafka, so you would need to configure Kafka exporter to use Jaeger data format. This is solved in Jaeger v2 https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/issues/4868.

Tip: questions are not an ideal place to ask for clarifications. Ideally, put your requests for clarifications in the comments, and your answer material in the answers. (You can do the two things in parallel if you wish; then, if you get a reply to your comment, you can update your answer).

I have already generated traces in otlp_json format. How can I create my own custom openetelemetry exporter using Python which will send those traces to Jaeger collector?
